# The server requested can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I deployed code on DigitalOcean and added and DNS successfully. But when I try to load the site from the browser it gets the following error:

> This webpage is not available

The server requested can't be found because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address.

This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet due to congestion or a misconfigured network.

It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing your browser from accessing the network.

Even though I am able to ping the site

Comment: Please provide your site url?

Comment: [http://bskcooler.in/]

Comment: Can you check that using ip you are able to access site?

Comment: Yes through IP i am able to access [http://174.138.36.4/]  and i am able to ping it from console

Comment: Which web server are you using on digital ocean nginx/apache?

Comment: There is some problem with DNS mapping. Visit this link:  [https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr%3a174.138.36.4&run=toolpage]. There is no DNS record found. You need to create ip and domain mapping.